# Getting information from a html file

Tags: java, html, parsing

I'm writing a program  where I get information from a page and put it in excel file.

The problem is, I don't find a way to search for the  tag with the specific info.

Here is my code(so far):

```
  private void getAll() throws IOException {

    for (int i = 0;i<250;i++){
        URL vurl = new URL("http://www.bamart.be/nl/artists/detail/" + i);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(vurl.openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
          if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("<div class=\"subcontent\">"){ 
            System.out.println("Found info!");
          }

            printInfo(line,i);
        }
        }
    }


private void printInfo(String info,int i){
        System.out.println("/***********************************************/");
        System.out.println("************\t" + info + "**********************/");
        System.out.println("/************" +" Artist page:" +  i + " of 999 **********************/" );


    }
```

The println doesn't come up, but it is in the html file.

Comment: Have a look at an external parser library maybe? try this: http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Already try'd that, didn't work, I found it a bit to hard with the changed api.

Comment: It really is your best bet; http://jsoup.org/ jsoup is probably a better bet and there are plenty of examples as-well! (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("<div class=\"subcontent\">"){ }
```

This if statement is checking for exact equality (ignoring case) however there could be other content on that line including whitespace for example.

What you might want instead would be something like

```
if (line.toLowerCase().contains("<div class=\"subcontent\">") { }
```

Comment: quick question, how would I go to get the closing tag?

Comment: You could continue parsing lines until one passes `if (line.toLowerCase().contains("</div>")`

Comment: Actually, I take that back -- if there is a nested div you'll have a problem.  If you need to get to this level of complexity, you might want to use an XML parser

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) starting with [this example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)